# Fragmented recovered image using a Phase Retrieval Algorithm named Error-Reduction

Tags: image-processing, matlab, algorithms, phase

After reading the paper [*Phase retrieval algorithms: a comparison*](http://digitus.itk.ppke.hu/~matyi/optika/Phase_Diversity/AO82_PRComparison.pdf) by J.R.Fienup. I implemented the *Error-Reduction Algorithm* in MATLAB. The initial phase input was randomly generated, so the final recovered image in each execution is different. The only information given is the Fourier Modulus of the original image.
Sometimes I can get a pretty well result, but most of the time the result is a fragmented version of the original image as the figures below shown:
[image: The Recovered Image] [image: The Original Image:$\pi$] 
As you can see, the image of $\pi$ is "almost" recovered except that the head and the body of $\pi$ had been cut and swapped. 
**My questions** are:
1. Is this a common problem using phase retrieval algorithm? What causes this?
2. Is there any method to avoid this?
3. Is there any other great methods in phase retrieval?

Comment: There is a $\pi /2$ phase shift in Matlab `fft/fft2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the effect you're seeing can be explained in terms of the shift theorem of Fourier transforms and the periodicity of the discrete Fourier transform.

It looks like the recovered object has been shifted upwards, and because the DFT is periodic, the top part of the object that's left the field of view has wrapped around to re-appear at the bottom of the field.
The reason the object is shifted is hard to see without knowing more about how your implementation of phase retrieval.  I can say that, due to the shift theorem, we know a shift in the object domain causes a linear phase in the Fourier domain, but does not affect the Fourier modulus.  So, the Fourier modulus alone can't help you find the correct shift.
I suspect you're leaving out some key information when you say "The only information given is the Fourier Modulus", because if that were strictly true you wouldn't be able to do phase retrieval at all.  As discussed in the paper, you need to have some other piece of information, typically the modulus of the object or the object support (the object support is a closed boundary that you know contains the object).  If you know the modulus of the object or at least its support, then reinforcing that constraint on every iteration of the error-reduction algorithm would prevent the object estimate from shifting.

As to your third question, I would point out that error-reduction is only the simplest algorithm discussed in the paper.  Gradient searches or the input-output methods described in the later sections are usually faster and/or more reliable.  In more recent years, successful methods that leverage nonlinear optimization algorithms such as BFGS have also become common. If you're interested, you might check out Prof. Fienup's [list of publications](http://www.optics.rochester.edu/workgroups/fienup/Publications.htm).

Comment: Thank you @user966000 for your detailed answer.  This experiment is done by following these step:

Comment: 1) Draw the white color pattern $\pi$ in a 100by100 black image;   2) Use `imread` to load the .bmp image as a matrix `p`;   3) Calculated its Fourier modulus matrix as `absP`;   4) Use random phase `theta` to form a Fourier domain guess `G_pr`.   5) Inverse transform `G_pr` to `g_pr`;   6) As the phase of `p` is a zero matrix, we let the some elements of `g_pr`, whose phase values are too big, be zero;   7) Keep the real part of `g_pr` ;  8)FFT `g_pr` into `G` and only keep its phase as `theta` then back to step 4.

Comment: Here is the Matlab code: <br/>  `format long
p=imread('pi.bmp');
P=fftshift(fft2(p));
absP=abs(P);
k=0;
theta=2*pi.*rand(100)-pi; %[-pi,pi]
figure(1)
figure(2)
while k<8000
    G_pr=absP.*exp(1i.*theta);
    g_pr=ifft2(ifftshift(G_pr));
    absPhase=abs(angle(g_pr));
    maxPh=max(max(absPhase));
    minPh=min(min(absPhase));
    g_pr(absPhase>=(minPh+0.2*(maxPh-minPh)))=0;
    g_pr=real(g_pr);
    gg=255*g_pr/(max(max(g_pr)));
   figure(1),imshow(uint8(gg));
    G=fftshift(fft2(g_pr));
    G=G./abs(G);
   theta=angle(G);
   figure(2),imshow(theta),title(num2str(k))
   k=k+1;
end` <br/>

Comment: @Mr.Who Thanks for code and outline. From those I can see that, besides knowing the Fourier modulus, you also assume that the object is real-valued and non-negative.  So, that's enough information that we can reasonably expect the results you're getting.  However, you'll need some more data and/or assumptions if you want to resolve the ambiguity in the shift I described earlier.  That could be as simple as including a support constraint, though.